# cocos2d push scene with transition

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, scene

Im using cocos2d v2.1 beta2 (not sure if important or not).

Im using `CCDirector` to push a scene. Im doing it like so: `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[CCTransitionFadeUp transitionWithDuration:1 scene:[ShopLayer scene]]];`
The problem is that in the beginning the scene appears for a split second and then the transition is performed.
How do I fix this? Will I really have to switch to `replaceScene:`?

Comment: try with replaceScene just to see if it shows the same effect. If it does, it's a different prob.

Comment: Well that was a surprise. It seems it is a different problem. Replace scene did the same split second appear then the transition started. How to I fix it?

Comment: Which transition are you trying?

Comment: CCTransitionFadeUP, ive replaced it with CCTransitionSlideInT and its working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed this.

I replaced the transition with `CCTransitionSlideInL`. Its working now.